# MonacaでGoogle Oauth 2.0認証を行う方法

Tags: javascript, ios, monaca, oauth, google-api

初めてこちらで質問させていただきます。
　
MonacaでiOS,Android対応のgoogle連携アプリケーションを制作しています。
今まで、googleのOAuth認証をwebviewで行っていたのですが、
2017年4月20日以降、代替手段を実際に利用できるプラットフォームにおいて、
WebViewを使ったすべてのOAuthクライアントはGoogleによってブロックされるとのことで
代替案として、cordova-plugin-googleplusのプラグインを使用し、
Google Oauth認証を行いたいと考えております。

Monaca上でcordova-plugin-googleplusをインポートし、
googleDeveloperConsole上でgoogle-services.json、GoogleService-Info.plistを生成まではでき、以下の関数を作成し、htmlにあるボタンにこの関数をつけましたが動作しません。
cordova-plugin-googleplusをMonacaで使用する際の手順、方法などを教えていただけますでしょうか？

```
function googlePlusTest(){

    console.log("googlePlusTest Login");      
    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
        {
           'scopes':'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks',
           'webClientId':'取得したクライアントID',
           'offline':true,
        },


        function(obj){
            alert('login succeeded');
            alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
        },

        function(msg){
            alert('error : ' + msg);
        }
    );        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Communityによって上がってきたので現状の回答を……

GooglePlusを用いたAPIサービスは、2019年3月7日を以って終了いたしました。
https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown?hl=ja

ですので、現在の回答としては**実装は出来ない**ということになります。

Answer (score 0):

動作しないというのは、errorのコールバックが呼ばれてしまうということでしょうか？
それとも、success、errorのどちらのコールバックも呼ばれない状態でしょうか？

iOS、Android対応と述べていますが、タグではiosとなっていましたので、iosの場合について確認させてください。

1. Cordovaプラグインの設定で
   REVERSED_CLIENT_ID
   の設定はしましたでしょうか？
2. Monacaデバッガーではなく、デバッグビルドで確認していますか？

またAndroidの場合についての補足ですが、keystore aliasのフィンガープリントが
必要になるため、現行のMonacaでデバッグビルドでは利用出来ないと思います。
リリースビルドであれば、keystore aliasのフィンガープリントをkeytoolコマンド
で確認すればいけると思いますが、、。